# Import Points from QGIS into AutoCAD

Tags: qgis, import

I want to know how to import points from QGIS into AutoCAD. My points have certain coordinates for X and Y and when importing them into AutoCAD they should have the same coordinates as in QGIS.

Is there any easy and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just "save As" your point layer to a DXF file from QGIS by right click on the layer. Be sure the CRS is right.
After that, you can import this DXF file to AutoCAD.

[image: Save As]

Answer (score 0):

you also can use the OSgeo4W Shell:

- Navigate to your folder where your shapefile is located
- use this comand:

  ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf input.shp
- ignore the warnings you will get
- you can also add a height field with the zfield argument like this:

  ogr2ogr -f DXF output.dxf input.shp -zfield hight

Answer (score -4):

For all details visit here
[How to plot AutoCad drawing in google earth | Create Kml , Kmz file](https://www.publicnengineers.com/2019/05/autocad-to-google-earth-kml-kmz.html)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  An answer should be self-contained, using links only as reference, not as the answer.  Please [edit] your answer to include all the steps provided to answer the question.  Links can change or disappear over time, so link-only answers are not accepted and may be deleted.